# Vue 3 scrollBehavior async scrolling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I'm trying to resolve a promise in the scrollBehavior function in vue 3. The vue router documentation is vague in regards to async scrolling (https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling).

With vue 2 I would have done something like this:

```
scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const position = (function () {
      if (savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition;
      }
    })();
    router.app.$root.$once("triggerScroll", () => {
      router.app.$nextTick(() => resolve(position));
    });
  });
};
```

But since vue 3 removed the events api, this can no longer be done. How can I resolve the promise at the end of a page transition? I could use a library like tiny-emitter, but I would prefer to learn how to do this without.

In the router.js :

```
scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const position = (function () {
      if (savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition;
      }
    })();

    // Listen to an event here to resolve, but how ?
    // resolve(position));
  });
};
```

Transition afterEnter function:

```
function afterEnter(router, trans) {
  // Do something here to trigger to resolve the promise
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Review the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html) related to the events API being removed. Perhaps one of the suggested solutions there can be helpful.